# Are tickets actualy illegitimate

Tags: united-states

Tickets are a *de facto* road toll and are therefore federally prohibited. Since you can be ticketed just before entering a highway they are a de facto FHWA violation and a taking of property.

Also, local governments are violating their own zoning if they toll a road, and the state doesn't even give them the right to zone a toll road.

Comment: Seems to be a similar argument as raised by "Sovereign Citizens" for a lot of things...  And those arguments are knocked down all the time.

Comment: But why cant it be knocked down?

Comment: You have good quality answers which do just that.

Comment: Not really, it still means it's a road toll

Comment: Also if you leave a state to escape a ticket then states are restricting interstate commerce

Comment: Dan, I no longer care about your hand wavy attempts to get around things - at this point, it just feels like you are trolling.

Comment: It's a violation of federal law

Comment: Reminds me of tax laws, where bringing certain objections to your income tax in the USA will get you a fine just for bringing that argument. I wonder what kinds of arguments would get your lawyer into trouble if he tries them in court, but you are close to that.

Comment: But this isnt even income tax. This is government violating it's own zoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're wrong. [RCW 46.61.415](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=46.61.415) empowers local authorities to establish and change speed limits in Washington, and [ORC 4511.21](http://codes.ohio.gov/orc/4511.21) delegates the same power in Ohio. Whether or not a locality has the power to pass such laws depends on the laws of that state.

Comment: But federal law prohibits road tolls, and setting an illogical speed limit to collect tickets is a de facto road toll therefore a federal infraction

Comment: If that were the purpose, perhaps, but the purpose of speed limits is to make driving safe. The test would be an unreasonable speed such as 2 mph on a city street. Also, remember that that law only applies to Federal-aid highways.

Comment: But if a private company made a road with a contradictory speed limit to collect revenue it would be charged

Comment: Does the law only apply to federal highways? I'm pretty sure all toll roads are banned unless state authorized

Comment: Also, the statute you have for whasington doesnt authorize any means to enforce it, it just says the limit can be set

Answer (score 2):

## You're wrong

The power to make laws is irrelevant - what matters is where local government gets the power to enforce the law. That power is delegated them by the state which undoubtedly has the power to police and the power to delegate that power.

Comment: Lol, they aren't a road toll.  If you want to be a troll about otherwise common-sense concepts like "go too fast, get in trouble," take that to Reddit or something.  Also, imagine wanting the federal government to be able to overrule local control when it comes to how fast someone should travel on 3rd Street in Downtown Somewhere, America. Give me a break, man!

Comment: But if local control violates federla law its illegal